# Net6 / NetCore - Restart the application process

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

We are writing an SDK for our company where the SDK starts all application secrets independently the Hosting environment. (Azure/AWS/Openshift/IIS/etc...)
If the SDK startup fails then the process should be "restarted" in order that the next request should start all over again as it was the first request.

ej:

```cs
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
using MySDK.Core;
using MySDK.SEC;
using MySDK.SEC.Model;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder
    .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace)
    .AddConsole());

ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("Startup Initializer");

builder
    .Services
    .AddMySDK(builder.Configuration)
    .AddSEC(
        builder.Configuration,
        logger: logger,
        options: new MySDK.SEC.Model.SecOptions() {  
            Services = builder.Services,
            OnInitError = (object sender, MySDK.SEC.Events.ErrorEventArgs e) => {
                //- Here we need to stop the requests.
                //- The next request should start all over again from the begining "var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);"
            },
            OnUpdateSecret = (object sender, MySDK.SEC.Events.UpdateSecretsEventArgs e) => {
                //- Here we need to be able to do 2 things.
                //- 1- Call the SEC updater and update all the secrets for the app.
                //- 2- Restart the app so the next request starts all over again from the begining "var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);".
            }
        }
    );

//-- Start all DBContext using SDK configuration
//-- Init AzureAD using SDK configuration
//-- Init other components using SDK configuration


// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

...
...
...

app.Run();
```

We tried several codes all around ending and none worked.

Thanks,

Comment: For IIS I have it working now with this code in "OnInitError" ```c#                 var host = ((MySDK.Core.MySDK)sender).Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IHost>(); if (host != null) { host.StopAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }```

Comment: That doesn't look like the right code. It's unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @davidfowl, hi. Which part doesn't look like the right code? both codes are extracts of our working code. What we are trying to do is, under a Failure, to stop the app startup and restart it on the next request; this stop/restart will continue while the startup fails. We are managing all secret in a (TPAM like) application, and the secrets for each app will come from it. If we have a problem retreiving the secret, then the app should stop.

Comment: What is sender? Why are you building the service provider here and resolving a different host instance?

Comment: Hi @davidfowl, I would like to know the best way to implement this. (sender is an instance of "MySDK" which only has "Services" and not a service provider, thats why I did BuildServiceProvider here). What I did now is to add a property to get the ServiceProvider from MySDK instance (but it calls BuildServiceProvider inside). -- Why is here a different host instance? Getting the IHost from ServiceProvider isnt the main Host instance? --- thanks.

Comment: When you call "BuildServiceProvider()" it is creating a new instance of a service provider. This will create a new instance of all of the dependencies in the service provider. Each instance is a new universe of instances that are unrelated to each other.